# Displaying corresponding record Id based on clicking anchor tag click

Tags: lightning-aura-components

My requirement is based on account Id,I have to display that perticular account details.

For example In image showing that account id, I am clicking that accountId, how can I that perticular accountId  in  "articlURL" method

[image]

```
 <aura:component controller="S360_AccountController" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="Aclist" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="enableDetail" type="boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.enableDetail}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Aclist}" var="ac">
        <a onclick="{!c.articleUrl}" > 

            <c:S360_Child AccountList="{!ac}" /> 
        </a>
    </aura:iteration>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
       corresponding  Account Detail page
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

```
   ({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action=component.get("c.accountMethod");
    action.setCallback(this,function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state=="SUCCESS"){
            component.set("v.Aclist",response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    //alert(component.get("v.Aclist"));
},

articleUrl: function(component, event, helper) {

    component.set("v.enableDetail",false);
}
```

})

```
  public class S360_AccountController {
      @AuraEnabled
     public static List<Account> accountMethod(){
    return [select id,name from account];
}
```

}

childcomponent:

```
<aura:component >
     <aura:attribute name="AccountList" type="account"/>    
  <p>accountId: {!v.AccountList.Id}</p>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Hi Lightning Learner, this forum is intended to help you with specific problems you encoutner. You seem to be asking alot of basic How To questions. I would recommend you the lightning component modules at [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) in order to get familair with the aura framework and lightning components in General

Comment: Nothing that you cant learn from Trailheads, I insist you go do the modules based on your recent question history. In the meantime, I am voting to close this question since none of your code seems related to a problem you have encoutnered, but rather, asking how to do something well documented.

Comment: If you update your post with what you have tried and what problem you are facing, you might get a better response from the community, however, as mentiond above, As is, this is a Basic How to question.

Answer (score 1):

Please take note of the following from the [Lightning Component Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_supported_html_tags_a.htm):

> Don’t hard code or dynamically generate Salesforce URLs in the href
>   attribute of an  tag. Use events, such as force:navigateToSObject
>   or force:navigateToURL, instead.

I strongly encourage you to search before posting as well as reading the developer documentation guide.

There is also an extensive list of Lightning Components that can be found at [Component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref.htm)

Long story short, avoid using anchor tags.